# Inconsistent calls from service broker to SQL dependecy

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, service-broker, sqldependency

I have this code working flawlessly for more than a year, but recently it became inconsistent.

I am using the `SqlDependecy` feature to subscribe queries to my SQL Server database that should notify my for changes.

My code goes as normal calling

`SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString)`

on the `Application_start()` of the system, and subscribing queries like

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("valid sql query for sqldependecy", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) { }
                }
            }
```

and resubscribing after every OnChange call. But recently Service Broker stopped notifying my application that there is changes on the queries. Sometimes it works, like the first time I try it on the day, but after that the OnChange is never called anymore, even if I restart the application. This problem happens with the application running in debug mode locally and in production server too.

I tried creating a new queue on Service Broker based on some very confusing instructions that I found in Microsoft's Website, something like

```
CREATE QUEUE queuetest;  

CREATE SERVICE queuetestNotifications  
  ON QUEUE queuetest  
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

and using this queue on the application, calling the method start with the queue parameter

```
SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString, "queuetest");
```

At first I got the very same behavior as utilizing the SqlDependecy without this, but after a while it evens began to throw `KeyNotFoundExceptions` when trying to start with the "queuetest" parameter.

Now I just don't know what else to try to make things work like it did in the past. The application code was not changed and the environment that worked before now doesn't. Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code closes the connection immediately?

From the docs:

> "The dependency infrastructure relies on a SqlConnection that is
>   opened when Start is called in order to receive notifications that the
>   underlying data has changed for a given command"

Now, connections will be pooled, so perhaps before, your connection was remaining open even though your had disposed of the object? or you had a race condition that happened to fall in your favour?

Why not keep the connection open for the duration of the application, rather than resubscribing when the notification is called?

Comment: But I think the connection is open for the duration of the application. If I'm not mistaken, the connection with the service broker begins on SqlDependency.Start() call, and I call this on the application_start, so it should remain open as long as the application is running. If this is wrong, how should I start the sqldependency to make it always open?

Comment: you are closing it when the using block ends. declare it as a member of application and close and dispose it on application exit

Comment: It is the exact same code, but instead of using the connection like in this block, I declared a global connection on the Application and opened it on Application_Start()